# Как подружить UIlabel и UItextField с численными значениями (Xcode)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Всем здравия. Не так давно начал изучать программирование под iOS, и очень быстро возник вопрос следующего содержания:

Для UIlabel и UItextField есть атрибут text, который работать с int и ему подобными напрочь отказывается. Других я найти не могу, даже на сайте Apple. В итоге, я могу написать только что-то подобное:

```
-(IBAction)btn:(id)sender {
    textField.text = @"Hey";
    textLabel.text = textField.text;
}
```

Поиск в Интернете дал сведения про некую конвертацию NSString в NSInteger, но она мне непонятна.

Мои цели:

Есть кнопка, label и textfield. Допустим, ввожу я с клавиатуры в textField какое то значение, пусть 33000, нажимаю кнопку, и на лейбле выводится какое то другое число, скажем, 10000. Проще говоря, конвертер чего-либо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (IBAction) btn:(id)sender {
    int myInteger = [self.textField.text intValue];
    int result = myInteger * 2;
    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", result];
}
```